# DataFrame resample on date ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that has the columns
'start_time' (datetime), 'end_time' (datetime), 'mode' and some other columns.
There is no overlap in the ranges of different rows of the table.

I would like to create a new DataFrame, that resamples each row of the original DataFrame like so:
'current_time', 'mode', other columns

Where 'current_time' is a resample between original 'start_time' and 'end_time' with a given frequency, and all other columns are just copies of values from the original table.

Example:
original DataFrame:

```
             start_time                   end_time   mode
2017-06-01 06:38:00.000 2017-06-01    06:39:00.000      x
2017-06-01 17:22:00.000 2017-06-01    17:22:30.000      y
```

For a given 'freq' of '10S', I'd like to get the following DataFrame:

```
           current_time     mode
2017-06-01 06:38:00.000        x
2017-06-01 06:38:10.000        x
2017-06-01 06:38:20.000        x
2017-06-01 06:38:30.000        x
2017-06-01 06:38:40.000        x
2017-06-01 06:38:50.000        x
2017-06-01 17:22:00.000        y
2017-06-01 17:22:10.000        y
2017-06-01 17:22:20.000        y
```

I'm looking for a reasonably efficient and elegant way of doing this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
#convert columns to datetimes if necessary
df['start_time']= pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
df['end_time']= pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'])
#subtract 10s for no last row from values from end_time column
df['end_time']= df['end_time'] - pd.Timedelta(10, unit='s')
```

---

```
#loop by list comprehension for list of date ranges
#concat to one big DataFrame
df1 = (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index, 
                           pd.date_range(r.start_time, r.end_time, freq='10S')) 
                           for r in df.itertuples()])
        .reset_index())
df1.columns = ['current_time','idx']
print (df1)
         current_time  idx
0 2017-06-01 06:38:00    0
1 2017-06-01 06:38:10    0
2 2017-06-01 06:38:20    0
3 2017-06-01 06:38:30    0
4 2017-06-01 06:38:40    0
5 2017-06-01 06:38:50    0
6 2017-06-01 17:22:00    1
7 2017-06-01 17:22:10    1
8 2017-06-01 17:22:20    1
```

EDIT by comment of OP:

If use parameter `closed=left`:

```
pd.date_range(r.start_time, r.end_time, freq='10S', closed='left')
```

then is possible omit subtracting.

---

```
#join all another columns by index
df2 = df1.set_index('idx').join(df.drop(['start_time','end_time'], 1)).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
         current_time mode
0 2017-06-01 06:38:00    x
1 2017-06-01 06:38:10    x
2 2017-06-01 06:38:20    x
3 2017-06-01 06:38:30    x
4 2017-06-01 06:38:40    x
5 2017-06-01 06:38:50    x
6 2017-06-01 17:22:00    y
7 2017-06-01 17:22:10    y
8 2017-06-01 17:22:20    y
```

Another solution:

```
#create column from index for last join (index values has to be unique)
df = df.reset_index()
#reshape dates to datetimeindex
df1 = (df.melt(df.columns.difference(['start_time','end_time']),
              ['start_time', 'end_time'],
              value_name='current_time')
        .drop('variable', 1)
        .set_index('current_time'))
print (df1)
                     index mode
current_time                   
2017-06-01 06:38:00      0    x
2017-06-01 17:22:00      1    y
2017-06-01 06:38:50      0    x
2017-06-01 17:22:20      1    y

#group by index column and resample, NaNs are replaced by forward filling
df2 = df1.groupby('index').resample('10S').ffill().reset_index(0, drop=True).drop('index', 1)
print (df2)
                    mode
current_time            
2017-06-01 06:38:00    x
2017-06-01 06:38:10    x
2017-06-01 06:38:20    x
2017-06-01 06:38:30    x
2017-06-01 06:38:40    x
2017-06-01 06:38:50    x
2017-06-01 17:22:00    y
2017-06-01 17:22:10    y
2017-06-01 17:22:20    y
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the first solution, with a small modification:    
`pd.date_range(r.start_time, r.end_time, freq='10S', closed='left')`

Comment: Super, it is nice improvement.